# A browser that supports multiple cached relations? (multiple accounts -- one browser -- re-openable)

Tags: web-browser

I have the need to be logged in to multiple accounts on the same website simultaneously, and for ease of use, remain logged in as well.

My current solution is to use 3 browsers which as you can imagine is quite inefficient. I've looked into Ghost Browser which supports tab-isolates sessions, but is there a tool, plugin or browser that would support caching these sessions as well?..

I can imagine it working like some sort of a bookmark, where all lead to the same website, but as a different session and separate cache/cookies, so that each of these tab bookmarks would also already be logged in with a respective account on the same website.

Does anything like this exist?

Answer (score 1):

The desktop version of [Firefox by Mozilla](https://www.mozilla.org/firefox) can accomplish this efficiently.

It's gratis (free of change) and [100% open-source](https://searchfox.org/).

It is [cross-platform, being available for Linux, Windows, and macOS](https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/system-requirements).

Just create a new container for each account.  Cookies and other session data are stored independently for each container.

You can basically have as many containers as you like.  I'm sure there must be an upper limit, but I've had hundreds of containers open at one time without any difficulty.